# PowerShell find-item doesn't return values

Tags: powershell-extensions, indexing

I'm currently using find-item on Sitecore PowerShell

`Find-Item -Index sitecore_master_index -Criteria @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "recipe id"; Value = "Recipe_Lambada"}, @{Filter = "DescendantOf"; Field = $SiteItem}`

Somehow, suddenly it stopped returning anything on the find item. I am sure this was working before as I have used it earlier.

Assuming Items do exist, am i doing something wrong here for find-item to be used?

I have tried reindexing the `sitecore_master_index`, published the templates of the item. I tried searching for the template and it seems to give me back results. What seems to be the problem here is that the field is not being seen.

Is there anything else that I miss? Or is there something else I can check?

Comment: Having the same issue.  Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I used Get-Item -Path master: -Query() instead.